# How to use maven-jar-plugin to create a test-jar with .class files?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jar

I have been trying to create a test-jar from a war project using the maven-jar-plugin. I have custom src folder which I want as a jar. The plugin does not compile the files in the folder and creates a jar with .java files. How do I compile the java files before they are packaged in a jar as .class files ?

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.4</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <goals>
            <goal>test-jar</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
   <configuration>
      <testClassesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/selenium</testClassesDirectory>   
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using maven-compiler-plugin

Comment: Yes I did but still does not compile the files from custom src folder in the jar.

Comment: Is it throwing any errors? Can you also please share your project structure

Comment: There are no errors while building the project. The test-jar which is built by maven-jar-plugin only contains java files which are not compiled. 
The structure is same as a maven project but only a new src folder (src/test/selenium) has been added which contains all the files I need in the jar.

Comment: projectname/src/main/java... try to keep all your class files under java and try

Comment: Not `src/main/java` but `src/test/java`.